# How to properly resize divs

Tags: html, css

In this jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/centem/L1r5pskb/6/) I'm trying to increase the width of each square so that I can put hostnames inside the box (2 hostnames) but if I try to increase the width of the squares (in the ".col-md-4 .row div" class) it no longer displays in the format illustrated in the picture attached. What is the proper way to do this so that the text fits inside the square? Thank you.

/* the css for the squares */

```
.col-md-4 .row div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    /*padding: 5px;*/
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    /*word-wrap: break-word;*/
    text-align: center;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `it no longer displays in the format illustrated in the picture attached` ==> where?

Comment: u want to increase  the width of blackbox ?

Comment: Yes. So I can had two hostnames. But everything get misaligned. I'm trying to keep the format of 3 columns with 3 rows each inside the columns.

Comment: u hav 4 items on your 2nd col

Comment: Yes that's on purpose because there are those many systems in real world that I am trying to model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167253/discussion-between-anuresh-and-stuttgarter-hofbrau).